Cómo aplicar correctamente estilos CSS sobre gráficos en JavaFX
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de gestión bancaria en JavaFX que incluye un gráfico de línea para mostrar datos financieros. He logrado modificar la mayoría de los elementos visuales en el gráfico, como el fondo, las etiquetas de los ejes y la leyenda. Sin embargo, tengo problemas para cambiar el color de los valores de los ejes X e Y (los números que marcan los puntos específicos en los ejes, no las etiquetas que indican el nombre de cada eje).
He probado los siguientes enfoques pero ninguno parece afectar los valores de los ejes:
.tick-label {
    -fx-fill: #e0e0e0 !important;
}

.x-axis .tick-label, .y-axis .tick-label {
    -fx-fill: #e0e0e0 !important;
}

Si alguien pudiera ayudarme a modificar los colores de esos valores estaría muy agradecido.
Además tengo el problema de que el padding en el textArea se crea con u color predeterminado y tampoco consigo modificarlo directamente. Comparto a continuación mi archivo darkTheme.css por si alguien se anima a revisarlo y echarme un cable :)
/*mainDarkTheme*/
.root {
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

/*botones*/
.button {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-text-fill: #e0e0e0;
    -fx-font-size: 12px;
    -fx-border-color: #555555;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-radius: 5px;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-padding: 8px 16px;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 2, 0, 0, 1);
    -fx-cursor: hand;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
    -fx-transition: background-color 0.3s, text-fill 0.3s;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #4b4e50;
    -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
}

.button:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: #5a5d60;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.3), 4, 0, 0, 2);
}

/*etiquetas*/
.custom-label {
    -fx-text-fill: #e0e0e0;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.custom-label1 {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-padding: 3 10 3 10;-fx-alignment: center;
    -fx-border-color: #e0e0e0;
    -fx-text-fill:#f0f0f0;
    -fx-border-width: 2px;
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
}

/*textArea*/
.custom-text-area {
    -fx-control-inner-background: #3c3f41;
    -fx-text-fill: #e0e0e0;
    -fx-border-color: #666666;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-padding: 8px 2px 10px 2px;
}


/*textField*/
.custom-text-field {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-text-fill: #c0c0c0;
    -fx-border-color: #555555;
    -fx-border-width: 1px;
    -fx-border-radius: 4px;
    -fx-background-radius: 4px;
    -fx-padding: 6px 10px;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 1, 0, 0, 1);
    -fx-transition: border-color 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
}

.custom-text-field:hover {
    -fx-border-color: #888888;
}

.custom-text-field:focused {
    -fx-border-color: #00aaff;
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0,170,255,0.3), 4, 0, 0, 2);
}

/*eliminar barra de desplazamiento horizontal (visual) */
.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-hbar-policy: never;
    -fx-vbar-policy: never;

}


/*gráfico*/
.axis-label, .chart-title{
    -fx-text-fill: #e0e0e0;
}

.chart {
    -fx-background-color: #2b2b2b;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}

.chart-plot-background {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
}

.chart-legend {
    -fx-background-color: #3c3f41;
    -fx-text-fill: #e0e0e0;
}

.chart-legend-item {
    -fx-text-fill: #e0e0e0;
}


Por si hay alguien curioso o interesado, he resuelto el problema del color de los valores de la siguiente manera:
.axis {
    -fx-tick-label-fill: #e0e0e0;
}

Aún sigo intentando modificar el color del padding de los textAreas por si alguien se anima...
